# Identify first child & align Text Center of Div using CSS

Tags: html, css

I need to update the first child property to display none so that the DIV's will look like a process.

```css
#crumbs a div:first-child{
 display: none; 
}
```

[JS Fiddler link here](https://jsfiddle.net/tngpdz9r/9/)

Also, the text is not aligning to the center. 
Any help in implementing this in CSS will be appreciated

Comment: Use class, you can't have multiple id's. Also, do you need div inside both a tags set to display:none, or just in FIRST crumbs block?

Comment: You can't have same `id` multiple times in a single web page.

Comment: @MuhammadUsman `can't` or `shouldn't` :)

Comment: @RajshekarReddy I mean this is something that is invalid.

Comment: `DIV's will look like a process.` what do you mean by this

Comment: @MuhammadUsman its just a bad practice and open for bugs (when CSS, Javascript are used on those elements), But I don't think its invalid.

Comment: I mean Process flow and also the DIV's doesn't have same ID's but the anchor tag can have.. I think it is doable.

Comment: @RajshekarReddy [W3C Markup Validator](https://validator.w3.org/) considers a document invalid if it contains duplicate ids.

Comment: @MuhammadUsman agree.. But I meant to say it just doesn't break the HTML ..

Comment: @RajshekarReddy Reputable web development companies never deliver invalid HTML document to their clients. Each and every HTML page is validated. If it doesn't break any thing then it doesn't mean that it is all good.

Comment: @MuhammadUsman I didnt say its all good.. I said its not invalid but a bad practice.. there is a difference.. `invalid` means something that will cause a break..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing is div id always should be unique. So use div class name rather div id(crumbs). and use css like this:

```
div.crumbs:first-child{
  display: none; 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for reply. But I am trying to create the first node as shown in this link http://line25.com/tutorials/how-to-create-flat-style-breadcrumb-links-with-css in the fiddle which I posted in the question.

Comment: In that case you can add       div.crumbs:first-child::before{ display:none;} and        div.crumbs:first-child { border-top-left-radius: 10px; border-bottom-left-radius: 10px; }

Comment: Can we do it using the same ID #Crumbs instead of creating class? Is it possible using the ID passed to the DIV? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Actually you cannot use same id for more than one div. That is why use of class name is perfect.

Answer (score 0):

For center align the Spans in the DIV the below code helps:

```css
#abc{
  font:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
  font-size:18px;
  text-align:left;
  background-color:#0F0;
  height:50px;
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

#abc span {
  vertical-align:middle;
  display: table-cell;
}
```